# telephonyManager.listen not working after targetSdkVersion is set to 31 or android 12

Tags: java, android

After i upgrade the targetSdkVersion to 31 telephonyManager.listen is not working. Consider following line of code:

telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

The logcat error message is as given below:

```
2022-02-27 13:51:36.313 6426-6426/com.example.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.app, PID: 6426
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.example.app.myPlayService@7ace64e with Intent { cmp=com.example.app/.myPlayService (has extras) }: java.lang.SecurityException: listen
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:4657)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:247)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2091)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
 Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: listen
    at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2425)
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2409)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2392)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2334)
    at com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephonyRegistry$Stub$Proxy.listenWithEventList(ITelephonyRegistry.java:1036)
    at android.telephony.TelephonyRegistryManager.listenFromListener(TelephonyRegistryManager.java:250)
    at android.telephony.TelephonyManager.listen(TelephonyManager.java:5999)
    at com.example.app.myPlayService.onStartCommand(myPlayService.java:186)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:4639)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:247) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2091) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003) 
 Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
    at com.android.internal.telephony.TelephonyPermissions.enforceCarrierPrivilege(TelephonyPermissions.java:634)
    at com.android.internal.telephony.TelephonyPermissions.checkReadPhoneState(TelephonyPermissions.java:149)
    at com.android.internal.telephony.TelephonyPermissions.checkCallingOrSelfReadPhoneState(TelephonyPermissions.java:94)
    at com.android.server.TelephonyRegistry.checkListenerPermission(TelephonyRegistry.java:3093)
    at com.android.server.TelephonyRegistry.listen(TelephonyRegistry.java:1024)
```

I have added following permission on the Android Manifiest file but still not working.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Before targeting below 31 or Android 12 it was working perfectly. How to solve this problem on Android SDK 31 ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm calling that API and I'm targeting API 31 so it should be possible. And I don't need the READ_PHONE_STATE permission

Answer (score 16):

When target API 31 [TelephonyManager.listen](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#listen(android.telephony.PhoneStateListener,%20int)) gives: `java.lang.SecurityException: listen`

So does [TelephonyManager.registerTelephonyCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#registerTelephonyCallback(java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20android.telephony.TelephonyCallback)), Except when [ENABLE_GET_CALL_STATE_PERMISSION_PROTECTION](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/reference/compat-framework-changes#enable_get_call_state_permission_protection) is disabled.

Developer Options / App Compatibility Changes / Select Application / Enabled for targetSdkVersion >= 31

Since [TelephonyManager.listen](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#listen(android.telephony.PhoneStateListener,%20int)) is deprecated in API level 31 and [TelephonyManager.registerTelephonyCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#registerTelephonyCallback(java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20android.telephony.TelephonyCallback)) is added in API level 31, you should make code like this:

**UPDATE** added examples for `callStateListener` and `phoneStateListener`

```
    private void registerCallStateListener() {
        if (!callStateListenerRegistered) {
            TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    telephonyManager.registerTelephonyCallback(getMainExecutor(), callStateListener);
                    callStateListenerRegistered = true;
                }
            } else {
                telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
                callStateListenerRegistered = true;
            }
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
    private static abstract class CallStateListener extends TelephonyCallback implements TelephonyCallback.CallStateListener {
        @Override
        abstract public void onCallStateChanged(int state);
    }

    private boolean callStateListenerRegistered = false;

    private CallStateListener callStateListener = (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) ?
            new CallStateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCallStateChanged(int state) {
                    // Handle call state change
                }
            }
            : null;

    private PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.S) ?
            new PhoneStateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String phoneNumber) {
                    // Handle call state change
                }
            }
            : null;
```

Links to documentation:

- [TelephonyCallback.CallStateListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyCallback.CallStateListener)
- [PhoneStateListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener).

Because [TelephonyCallback.CallStateListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyCallback.CallStateListener) requires [Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#READ_PHONE_STATE) and this permission has protection level dangerous, you should ask for run time permissions following this guide: [Request app permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)

Comment: Can you please put the code on how to declare callStateListener?

Comment: PhoneStateListener is it requires  Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE permission?

Comment: @AjitKumarDubey No PhoneStateListener does not require the READ_PHONE_STATE permission. It is however deprecated in API level 31.  Here you should instead use CallStateListener which does require the permission. Add the permission in AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: @user1801374 But my question here is how WhatsApp is doing. Without phone state permission they are handling the call state in API level 31. I had verified it and it's working fine.

Answer (score 6):

Your call to listen while providing the LISTEN_CALL_STATE will trigger onCallStateChanged() callback.

```
telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

As you can see in the docs, onCallStateChanged() requires the READ_PHONE_STATE if you target Android 31 or later.

> Requires Permission: READ_PHONE_STATE for applications targeting API
> level 31+.

See this:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener#onCallStateChanged(int,%20java.lang.String)

So, to solve this, **simply ask for the permission before you call the listen call** (but only when the code executes on Android 31+) as follows:

```
    // for API 31+: you need to first check for READ_PHONE_STATE permission to be able to listen to LISTEN_CALL_STATE
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 31)
    {
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }
    else // no permission needed
        telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is here looking for a Kotlin + Flow version of this code that supports both API <= 30 and API 31+ (since they have to be handled differently), here you go.

This assumes permissions are handled by the calling UI code.

```
val callState = callbackFlow {
    val telephonyManager = application.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager

    // The thread Executor used to run the listener. This governs how threads are created and
    // reused. Here we use a single thread.
    val exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 31) {
        // SDK >= 31 uses TelephonyManager.registerTelephonyCallback()

        val callback = object : TelephonyCallback(), TelephonyCallback.CallStateListener {
            override fun onCallStateChanged(state: Int) {
                trySend(Pair(state, null))
            }
        }
        telephonyManager.registerTelephonyCallback(exec, callback)

        awaitClose {
            telephonyManager.unregisterTelephonyCallback(callback)
            exec.shutdown()
        }
    }
    else {
        // SDK 30 uses TelephonyManager.listen()

        @Suppress("OVERRIDE_DEPRECATION")
        val callback = object : PhoneStateListener(exec) {
            override fun onCallStateChanged(state: Int, phoneNumber: String) {
                trySend(Pair(state, phoneNumber))
            }
        }
        telephonyManager.listen(callback, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE)

        awaitClose {
            telephonyManager.listen(callback, 0)
            exec.shutdown()
        }
    }
}.stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000), null)
```

The flow provides a `Pair<Int, String?>` where the `.first` is the call state and the `.second` is the phone number in API <= 30.

I have a full example of this working using Kotlin + Compose + Flows on my blog here: https://tdcolvin.medium.com/network-type-in-android-watching-for-5g-4g-3g-2g-capability-a52db23bf3bf

Answer (score 0):

this is the way I'm doing it:

```
    private suspend fun updateServiceState() {
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            telephonyManager.listen(object : PhoneStateListener() {
                override fun onServiceStateChanged(state: ServiceState) {
                    telephonyManager.listen(this, LISTEN_NONE)
                    ...
                }
            }, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SERVICE_STATE)

        }
    }
```

I'm targeting Android 12, API 31 and I don't have the READ_PHONE_STATE permission

Comment: can you convert the code in java? I do not know Kotlin.

Comment: Are you registering the listener in the main thread?

Comment: i have registered the listener on foreground service.

Comment: that still doesn't tell me whether it is in the main thread or not but I guess it is

Comment: yes its on main thread

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add the permission in your manifest, as you've done, as well is request it dynamically by calling `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()`

Fairly thorough doc on it: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting